# Работа с npm в python

Tags: python, npm

Я пишу программу, суть которой заключается в создании папки с веб-проектом. Я использую gulp, а устанавливается он при помощи npm (`npm i gulp --save-dev`). Можно ли при помощи питона сделать так, что бы в нужный момент в консоли, например, выполнялась команда: `npm i gulp --save-dev` и, тем самым, устанавливался npm модуль. Нагуглил только про модуль subprocess, но он, как мне показалось, не подходит для этой задачи, либо у меня просто руки кривые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы всё правильно нагуглили. Модуль subprocess позволяет вызывать любую команду, а `npm`, это и есть команда.

```py
subprocess.check_call('npm i gulp --save-dev', shell=True)
```